# How to reset a variable to 0 every 24 hours in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

I want to reset a variable automatically without any user interaction to 0 every midnight.

How to do that in vanilla Javascript?

Or does Chrome have any default method to do it. Because I store that variable in Chrome.storage.local.

What is the best way to do it in either vanilla JS or using chrome apis?

Comment: Is this a page that is loaded into a browser and is not reloaded across midnight?`

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your question.

Comment: Normally people navigate a site. You have a page, it has a variable, what is the usecase for the visitor? That some counter or a clock is reset if they visit and stay on the page over midnight? Or is it some monitoring page that is always loaded

Comment: It is a monitoring page. the variable changes as per the user action in the page. So I need to reset it to 0 everyday and count the user action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do so automatically without user accessing the page.

But, you can add script to the page which onload check the last time the value was stored and if the time passed you can reset the variable.

Rough code to make this:

```js
const isToday = (someDate) => {
  const today = new Date()
  return someDate.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
    someDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() &&
    someDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()
}

window.onload = function init() {
    const { value, date } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getValue('key'));
    
    if (!isToday(date)) {
        localStorage.setValue('key', JSON.stringify({ date: new Date(), value: defaultValue}))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've said you're storing the value in `Chrome.storage.local`. Also store the date/time you saved that value. When you load it, if midnight has passed since that time, reset the value to zero.

In case the page has been left open overnight, either always load the value from storage before using it (even if you already have it in a JavaScript variable), or do the same thing at the JavaScript level (remember the date/time and reset the value). Although you *can* set a timer, pages that sit idle for a long period of time have their timers de-prioritized by modern browsers, so it probably wouldn't be reliable to do this with a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said Chrome, I assume that you meant the browser, and the variable that you want to reset is in a client-side application (i.e., in the browser).

You can do it in two ways:

1. Using the client-side app only (i.e., without server assistance).
2. Using server assistance (i.e., with server assistance).

---

Here are insights into how to implement each:

1. Without server assistance: You may want to implement e.g., reset_variable() function to be scheduled with helping of [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). The idea is that you have to trigger setInterval() at midnight for the first time and adjust the interval to 24 hours. In order to do so, you will have to implement some algorithm to calculate when to start executing (i.e., trigger) setInterval() using the setTimeout().
2. With server assistance: You may want to implement a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)-like job in the server. The job may look like sending some predefined values to reset the variable on the browser.
   Therefore, you can do it in diverse ways. The simplest way is over [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

---

Explanation if you want to implement it *with assistance from the server side* (where my opinion is to go with, but still it depends on the context which is here not clear):

1. Browser/Client-side: Implement a Listener on the browser e.g., [message event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/message_event), whenever you caught a message, process that message if it's the predefined value to reset the variable, then someVar.reset().
2. Server-side: Create a handler to connect to the client-side WebSocket Listener -WebSocket is supported in most programming languages-.
   Implement a cron-like job to execute a function every midnight. I have no idea if you have a server, and if so, which programming language you are using. However, a cron-like job can be implemented in several programming languages, and basically, it can be implemented natively on Unix-like OSs, you may want to ask another question if you need help regarding this.
   The function should send a predefined value using the handler of the WebSocket connection.
   Note that you may want to do some security validation though.